# Infared light effect on animals

Tags: health, containment, guinea-pigs, lighting

I have built a Webcam with a raspberry pi. It is supposed to go in the house of our guineapigs to watch what their doing. The camera has no IR filter so I want to get some IR lights to give the camera night vision. Is there a risk for the guineapig when I let the lights run the hole night, or is the a power limit they they don't get harmed?
Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: the answer to your question can be found in the other question i linked to.for some additional information you can look here https://squeaksandnibbles.com/can-guinea-pigs-see-in-the-dark/

Comment: The hamster question was really helpful thanks.

Comment: I added an answer [here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/27130/16373).